# How to check if HTMLElement has already been generated?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

I have a component from 3rd party which emits "onCellEdit" event and passes a cell element as parameter.

In my event handler I want to automatically select the whole text in the input element that is generated inside of this cell.

The problem I'm having is that when my handler is triggered the input element is not yet loaded.
`(cellElement as HTMLTableCellElement).querySelector('input')` returns nothing since the 3rd party component needs some time I guess.

My solution now looks like this:

```
selectTextOnEdit(cell: HTMLTableCellElement) {
    const repeater = (element: HTMLTableCellElement) => {
      const inputElement = element.querySelector('input');
      if (inputElement) {
        inputElement.select();
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => { repeater(element); }, 50);
      }
    };
    repeater(cell);
  }
```

this function then triggers the repeater function which goes around until the input element is found. I know I'm missing some kind of a check in case the input element is never generated.. but it's not important for this question.

I highly dislike this solution and I'm sure there are better ones.

**Update:**

After some research I found out about "MutationObserver".

Here is my new solution:

```
selectTextOnEdit(cell: HTMLTableCellElement) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(mutation => {
        if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
          const inputElement = cell.querySelector('input');
          if (inputElement) {
            inputElement.select();
            observer.disconnect();
          }
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(cell, {childList: true});
  }
```

Comment: Please put your answer to this question into an answer and ask any new questions arising from it into a new question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am sorry but I'm quite new in asking questions on stackoverflow so I didn't fully understand your request. I should post an answer to my own question with a solution that is under section "update" in my og. question?

Comment: There is a box labeled "Your Answer" at the bottom of the screen. Put your answer in that box. Your new question, "How ever with this one I don't how to disconnect the observer if the input element is never created.?" should be a new question, since the answer you've already received does not answer that question, and can't, because you've changed the question after the answerer went through the trouble of writing an answer for your original question.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of scenarios, I like to use a utility function of `waitUntil`.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
export const waitUntil = async (untilTruthy: Function): Promise<boolean> => {
  while (!untilTruthy()) {
    await interval(25).pipe(
      take(1),
    ).toPromise();
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

Then in your function, it would be:

```
async selectTextOnEdit(cell: HTMLTableCellElement) {
    await waitUntil(() => !!cell.querySelector('input'));
    const inputElement = element.querySelector('input');
    inputElement.select();
  }
```

This is the same thing but slightly cleaner in my opinion. Why is it an issue that the `input` was never created, shouldn't always be created if the callback of `selectTextOnEdit` is called?

Comment: Because I can apply edit template to the cells. And if my edit template is without inputs they will never create.

Comment: I guess I could use rxjs's timeout to break from the loop but.. then I almost fancy my first solution over this.

Comment: Yea, it is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out about "MutationObserver".

Here is my new solution:

```
selectTextOnEdit(cell: HTMLTableCellElement) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(mutation => {
        if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
          const inputElement = cell.querySelector('input');
          if (inputElement) {
            inputElement.select();
            observer.disconnect();
          }
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(cell, {childList: true});
  }
```